# OperationalError: Can't start transaction Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, pgdb

I am running pgdb.connect to make a connection to my postgresql server and cursor to execute queries. For the first time (sometimes twice) it works properly but after that it gives me

**OperationalError: Can't start transaction**

on "cursor.execute(query)"

Can someone please help me on how to solve this error?

I am using docker compose with one containing postgresql and another a flask server.

Comment: please check what's in postgres logs

Comment: Is it something happened that transaction has started within transaction? if yes, remove it.